# TERMINATED message in thread join

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, pthreads

I am using pthreads on unix in socket programming. When the parent thread is waiting for it's child to join, I receive a message "Terminated" at the very end, this is not a statement that I am printing out from my program.

Could anybody help me and can tell what could be the reason for this message?

This happens when parent is waiting on join and child threads starts to exit, but eventually I am getting this message.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Terminated" message is printed by your shell since it noticed that your application was killed with a `SIGTERM`. This is likely due to a bug in your code - we'd need to see source in order to find it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, i got the hint from the SIGTERM, and I was able to debug, since I was sending the kill() with SIGTERM but wasn't using the signal() command to catch that signal.....thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

`Terminated` is often the output when a program is sent the `SIGTERM` signal:

Start this in one terminal:

```
$ sleep 10
Terminated
```

From another terminal:

```
$ killall sleep -SIGTERM
```

I'm not entirely sure why your process is receiving a `SIGTERM`, but I wonder if your child is calling `exit(2)` or `exit(3)` directly, rather than calling `pthread_exit(3)` or falling off the end of its function.